# XmlHttpRequest not working on on button click event

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, xmlhttprequest

I'm currently running into issue with XmlHttpRequest when handling a click event:

- onloaded doesn't get called
- onprogress or onreadystatechange always gets status 0

## Where it works:

- if I send the XmlHttpRequest outside this click event, i.e inside:
  `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",(e) =>.`
- Inside button click event BUT synchronous:
  `XmlHttpRequest.open("POST", url,  false)`

Thinking that it was a scope issue, I held a reference to this Request object:

## Scope Implementation

> ```
>   request = new Request(@_callback,"POST")
>   document
>   .getElementById 'LoginButton'
>   .addEventListener("click", @_performLogin);
> ```

```
  _callback : (err, response) ->
    if err then throw err
    console.log(response)
    console.log(response["status"])
    if response["status"] == 200 then alert("Login successful!") else alert("Login Failed")
```

class methods:

```
  _performLogin : () ->
    username = document.getElementById('username').value
    password = document.getElementById('password').value
    url = "https://dev.kittyhawk.io/api/login?email=" + username + "&password=" + password
    request._sendRequest(url)
```

Note: Request is just a wrapper for the XmlHttpRequest

Any idea as to what's going on?

Edit:
*Inside Request class*
Note that catch() doesn't get called, and send() gets executed but I see no network request in Chrome. And in Safari, I see the request in red (and no status). Also, very new to this, so please bear with me. :)

```
_sendRequest:(targetUrl) =>
    try
      if targetUrl? then @_url = targetUrl else new Error("Missing parameter: URL")
      @_request.open(@_type,@_url,true)
      @_request.send()
    catch e
      console.log(e)
      alert("Error:" + e)
```

Comment: did you inspect it?

Comment: Yeah, no errors as far as references. But, also not seeing network requests. Thanks for reminding, will add the details to my question.